# Same button on different div's with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have multiples divs on a page, each one one with 3 buttons that hide and show content inside of each div. The objective is exactly the same in both divs but what is happening is that when i press a button on the first div it also triggers the action on the other divs. How can i fix this? My idea is to have, for example, a unique id per div that allows me to use the same buttons across the page multiples times without having to repeat the JS code.

This is my initial code, and i want to be able to add something that i can use the buttons but only triggers inside the div their in.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

```js
$('.descontoBTN').on('click', function () {
    $(".pacote div").hide()
    $(".desconto").show()
    $('.descontoBTN').addClass('active')
    $('.mensalidadeBTN').removeClass('active')
    $('.tvBTN').removeClass('active')

});
$('.mensalidadeBTN').on('click', function () {
    $(".pacote div").hide()
    $(".mensalidade").show()
    $('.descontoBTN').removeClass('active')
    $('.mensalidadeBTN').addClass('active')
    $('.tvBTN').removeClass('active')

});
$('.tvBTN').on('click', function () {
    $(".pacote div").hide()
    $(".tv").show()
    $('.descontoBTN').removeClass('active')
    $('.mensalidadeBTN').removeClass('active')
    $('.tvBTN').addClass('active')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-12" id="pack1">

      <div class="pacote px-4 pt-4 pb-1">
        <div class="desconto">
          <h4><strong>TITLE1</strong></h4>
          <h6><del>€99,99/mês</del></h6>
          <h3>€93,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="mensalidade" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE2</strong></h4>
          <h6>1 Mensalidade</h6>
          <h3>€95,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="tv" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE3</strong></h4>
          <h6>TV 32"</h6>
          <h3>€95,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ofertas px-4 pb-1">
        <div class="btn-group d-flex gap-2" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 active descontoBTN">Desconto €3/mês</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 mensalidadeBTN">1 Mensalidade</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 tvBTN">TV 32"</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-12" id="pack2">

      <div class="pacote px-4 pt-4 pb-1">
        <div class="desconto">
          <h4><strong>TITLE1</strong></h4>
          <h6><del>€89,99/mês</del></h6>
          <h3>€83,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="mensalidade" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE2</strong></h4>
          <h6>2 Mensalidade</h6>
          <h3>€195,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="tv" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE3</strong></h4>
          <h6>TV 32"</h6>
          <h3>€295,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ofertas px-4 pb-1">
        <div class="btn-group d-flex gap-2" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 active descontoBTN">Desconto €3/mês</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 mensalidadeBTN">1 Mensalidade</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 tvBTN">TV 32"</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-12" id="pack3">

      <div class="pacote px-4 pt-4 pb-1">
        <div class="desconto">
          <h4><strong>TITLE1</strong></h4>
          <h6><del>€199,99/mês</del></h6>
          <h3>€193,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="mensalidade" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE2</strong></h4>
          <h6>1 Mensalidade</h6>
          <h3>€95,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="tv" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE3</strong></h4>
          <h6>TV 32"</h6>
          <h3>€95,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ofertas px-4 pb-1">
        <div class="btn-group d-flex gap-2" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 active descontoBTN">Desconto €3/mês</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 mensalidadeBTN">1 Mensalidade</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 tvBTN">TV 32"</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post the relevant html

Comment: Post the relevant HTML _**here**_ in your question. You can even create a runnable "stack snippet" similar to the fiddle you created.

Comment: Just did @StephenP thanks for the tip i'm new here =)

Comment: The problem is that you are repeating `id` names, for example you have multiple divs with `id="pacote"` — id names must be _unique_ within a page. When you have a repeated pattern of similar things you are better off using _classes_ instead of _ids_.

Comment: Sorry @StephenP i forgot to update the code to classes. Now you can really see what i'm talking about. I i press one button everything changes. What i need is a simple solution to have this running by each area without having to duplicate all the code with new classes etc. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of repeated code by creating an `eventHandler` to handle all button clicks.

**Updated**

I have adjusted the demo to use the HTML added to the question.  I am not sure if I have capture all your requirements but the amount of code duplication has been reduced.

**See demo below**

```js
$('.ofertas button').on('click', function() {
  // find closest parent 'group'
  let columnGroupElementId = $(this).closest('div.col-12').attr('id');
  let elementIdSelector = '#' + columnGroupElementId
  // hide all .pacote divs within it
  $(elementIdSelector).find(".pacote div").hide();

  // remove class from all buttons in it
  // the line below may or may not be needed, I am not sure of your requirements
  $(this).closest(".ofertas").find('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  // get a list of classes for selected button
  var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  var classNameToShow = '';

  // get the value of the class name that ends with BTN and use it as the class name to show
  $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
    var indexOfBtn = item.indexOf('BTN');
    if (indexOfBtn >= 0) {
      classNameToShow = item.substring(0, indexOfBtn);
      //console.log('-'+classNameToShow+'-');
    }
  });

  // show only the child of the selected one
  $(elementIdSelector).find("div." + classNameToShow).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12" id="pack1">
      <div class="pacote px-4 pt-4 pb-1">
        <div class="desconto">
          <h4><strong>TITLE1</strong></h4>
          <h6><del>€99,99/mês</del></h6>
          <h3>€93,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="mensalidade" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE2</strong></h4>
          <h6>1 Mensalidade</h6>
          <h3>€95,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="tv" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE3</strong></h4>
          <h6>TV 32"</h6>
          <h3>€95,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ofertas px-4 pb-1">
        <div class="btn-group d-flex gap-2" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 active descontoBTN" data-value="desconto">
            Desconto €3/mês
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 mensalidadeBTN" data-value="mensalidade">
            1 Mensalidade
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 tvBTN" data-value="tv">
            TV 32"
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-12" id="pack2">
      <div class="pacote px-4 pt-4 pb-1">
        <div class="desconto">
          <h4><strong>TITLE1</strong></h4>
          <h6><del>€89,99/mês</del></h6>
          <h3>€83,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="mensalidade" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE2</strong></h4>
          <h6>2 Mensalidade</h6>
          <h3>€195,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="tv" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE3</strong></h4>
          <h6>TV 32"</h6>
          <h3>€295,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ofertas px-4 pb-1">
        <div class="btn-group d-flex gap-2" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 active descontoBTN">Desconto €3/mês</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 mensalidadeBTN">1 Mensalidade</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 tvBTN">TV 32"</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-12" id="pack3">

      <div class="pacote px-4 pt-4 pb-1">
        <div class="desconto">
          <h4><strong>TITLE1</strong></h4>
          <h6><del>€199,99/mês</del></h6>
          <h3>€193,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="mensalidade" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE2</strong></h4>
          <h6>1 Mensalidade</h6>
          <h3>€95,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="tv" style="display:none;">
          <h4><strong>TITLE3</strong></h4>
          <h6>TV 32"</h6>
          <h3>€95,99<span>/mês</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ofertas px-4 pb-1">
        <div class="btn-group d-flex gap-2" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 active descontoBTN">Desconto €3/mês</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 mensalidadeBTN">1 Mensalidade</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark w-100 tvBTN">TV 32"</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks @blurfus, it works perfectly you're the man!!!! Amazing!

Comment: glad I could help... if you need to avoid the modal buttons being affected, you could try a different selector at the very beginning - like `$('.ofertas button').on(...){}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage `$(this)`. This is just a basic example of usage:

```
$('.myButtonClass').on('click', function(){
 $('.myButtonClass').not(this).hide()
 $(this).parent().find('.otherTargetedClass').addClass('active')
 $(this).siblings().fadeOut('slow')
 $(this).parent().show()
})
```

Also, it looks like you are using the `id` attribute the same as the `class` attribute. Id's are unique and there should never be duplicates of the same id on a page. Classes can be used multiple times on a page.

Comment: This is close but first you'd need to hide all the elements 'not clicked' and then show the one clicked using `this`.

Comment: I'm just using a broad example since you didn't post html just to give you an idea of how it works.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the new HTML